# Make a sprite get gradually get smaller pygame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I am trying to get a sprite in pygame to get gradually smaller while a key is held down. Is there any way this is possible?

I have got it to go to a set size on a single key tap with

```
self.img = pygame.transform.scale(self.img, (40, 40))
```

but i can not get it to go gradually smaller as you hold a key down.

thanks in advance!

Comment: why not just decrease the size by x for each iteration of the game loop while the key is pressed?

Comment: The problem with that is that you need a size to decrease form so you have to set a size before the main game loop, but that returns UnboundLocalError: local variable 'size' referenced before assignment @SirParselot

Comment: The image has an original size so just get that and that's your starting point

Comment: If you use that to decrease from (e.g. self.img = pygame.transform.scale(self.img, (start_size - x, start_size - x)) ) you will have to increase x so you are not doing the same thing over and over again, but that also returns UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment @SirParselot . I might just be being completely stupid here but i cant see a way of doing this

Comment: would `self.img = pygame.transform.scale(self.img, (self.img.get_width()-1, self.img.get_height()-1))` not give the desired result? In the method you described you would have to change `x` or change `start_size` to `current_size` which is what I just showed.

Comment: So i was being stupid! thanks a lot @SirParselot . if you give that as an answer i will accept it.

Comment: You might want to experiment with `smoothscale()` it might make your shrink look a little better

Comment: That works a lot better thanks @SirParselot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a fixed size you can get the current size of image and decrease it by `x` for each loop of the game while the key is pressed so all you need to do is change your scale line to

```
self.img=pygame.transform.scale(self.img, (self.img.get_width()-x, self.img.get_height()-x))
```